# Access violation reading location location 0x1D5C4C2F

Tags: c, memory, rgb

This function is throwing an access violation when reading raw pixel values and I can't figure out why.
Can consider this as the only part of my code running, I've run this solo with the same result.

```
string filenames[]={"firstclick.raw", "secondclick.raw","thirdclick.raw","fourthclick.raw","fifthclick.raw","sixthclick.raw","seventhclick.raw","eighthclick.raw"};
FILE *file;
int height= 750, width = 453, bbp=3;

unsigned char ****images;
images = (unsigned char ****)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char ***)*8);
for(int j = 0; j<8; j++){
    images[j] = (unsigned char ***)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char**)*height);
    for(int i = 0; i<height; i++){
        images[j][i]= (unsigned char **)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*)*width);
        for(int k = 0; k<bbp; k++)
            images[j][i][k]= (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*bbp);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i<8; i++){
    if (!(file=fopen(filenames[i].c_str(),"rb"))){
        cout << "Cannot open file: "<<filenames[i].c_str() <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    fread(images[i], sizeof(unsigned char), height*width*bbp, file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you've allocated each element of your array as a separate array (somewhere else in memory, whose location is kept as a pointer).  But when you read in, you assume that it's a single contiguous block.  You will overwrite all those pointers, and overflow the buffer to boot.

If you want `images` to be a set of discrete blocks of memory, allocate like this:

```
unsigned char ** images;
int i;

images = malloc( sizeof(unsigned char *) * 8 );
for( i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    images[i] = malloc( width * height * bpp );
}
```

Note that `sizeof(unsigned char)` is defined by the standard to always be 1.  You don't need to multiply by `sizeof(unsigned char)` all the time.

Now, to get a pixel address in an image, you need to multiply out (usually row-major):

```
unsigned char * pixel = images[i] + (y * width + x) * bpp;
unsigned char r = pixel[0];
unsigned char g = pixel[1];
unsigned char b = pixel[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

when you allocate the memory blocks in different locations in memory an fread on that structure will not work.

instead allocate one big block then set the pointers to point inside the block, that way you can use fread on it.

Comment: and if you allocate one block of memory do not try accessing it with multiple subscripts block[i][j][k]